# Can't get state from redux's store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm developing React/Redux application and I've got problem with getting one particular state from redux store after dispatching an action. I don't have any idea why is that happening, because I haven't experienced such issue with other states. Here is my code:

**Reducer**

```
import {SET_CURRENT_USER, SET_LECTURES} from '../actions/actionTypes';
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';

const initialState = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: {},
  lectures: []
}

export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
        return {
            isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user),
            user: action.user
        };
    case SET_LECTURES:
        return {
            lectures: action.lectures
          }
    default: return state;
    }
}
```

**Action creator and dispatching action**

```
import { SET_LECTURES } from './actionTypes';

export const setLectures = (lectures) => {
  return {
    type: SET_LECTURES,
    lectures
  }        
}
export const lecture = (lectures) => {
   return dispatch => {
    console.log(lectures);
    dispatch(setLectures(lectures));
  }
}
```

The problem is with `SET_LECTURES` action type, in particular `lectures` property of action object. In the component from which I want to get state `lectures`, I do `mapStateToProps` as follows:

```
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    notifications: state.notifications,
    lectures: state.lectures
  }
}
/*
*Code of the class
*/
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(AddQuestionForm);
```

I've skipped code which triggers dispatching action type `SET_LECTURES`, because it's working fine. I've also used React Developer Tools for tracking states, and there is `lectures` state. I just can't get this state from my component, when I do `console.log(this.props.lectures)` from `ComponentDidMount()`, it shows *undefined*. Could you explain what am I doing wrong here? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just try `console.log(this.props)` and paste the result

Comment: Maybe it's because of this: 

`return {
            isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user),
            user: action.user
        };`

You need to do `return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.user),
            user: action.user
        };`
because otherwise it'll overwrite lectures

Comment: @DusanJovanov That's also true

Comment: I did as @DusanJovanov said, but didn't help. These are my props from desired component:{**dispatch**: ƒ (t)
**history**:  {length: 17, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}
**lectures**:  undefined
**location**:  {pathname: "/addQuestion/3", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "a049sv"}
**match**:  {path: "/addQuestion/:id", url: "/addQuestion/3", isExact: true, params: {…}}
**notifications**:  []
**staticContext** : undefined
__proto__:  Object

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about `dispatch`:

```
export const lectureAction = lectures => dispatch => {
   return dispatch => {
    dispatch(setLectures(lectures));
  }
}
```

In Component:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
  return {
    notifications: state.notifications
  }
}

// use map dispatch for actions:
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => 
    bindActionCreators({
        lectures: lectureAction
    }, dispatch);

/*
*Code of the class
*/

// connect map dispatch here:
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddQuestionForm);
```

Now you have an access to `this.props.lectures(someParams)` function in your Component which dispatch an action.

Comment: please note, that `const someAction => (...) => (dispatch, getState) => { ... }` pattern requires redux-thunk applied to your store (https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

Comment: But what you did here isn't passing state to store by dispatching it? Because I written that I've already done passing state in another component by exactly mapDispatchToProps and now I want to get this state from another component, which you've mentioned.

Comment: And yes, I've got redux-thunk applied to my store :)

Comment: i got you! sorry :) can you show your mapDispatchToProps function? also try to debug this node in action creator an reducer

Comment: To be serious, my mapDispatchToProps looks just like this: `export default connect(mapStateToProps, { lecture })(Event);` And yes, I actually tried to debug this from both actionCreator and reducer by `console.log`, it succesfully shows what I wanted. And still can't get this in my another component :(

Comment: your mapDispatchToProps must be a function, with action wrapped by bindActionCreators (like i've written above), not object like `{ lecture }`
something like

````export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatch => bindActionCreators({ lecture }, dispatch))(AddQuestionForm);````

Comment: if you don't want to use bindActionCreators try this code

````const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
        lecture: () => dispatch(lectureAction())
});````

Comment: Okey, I've done it, but know when I want to trigger this action there is `TypeError: dispatch is not a function`. Googled that and found that I should pass actionCreator to `bindActionCreators`, so in my example actionCreator is `setLectures` am I right? Even with this it keeps displaying me this TypeError :/

Comment: Yes, it finally works!! I've used bindActionCreators and I got state from my desired component. Spend on this nearly enitre day. God bless you! :D

Comment: actually both `lecture` and `setLecture` are action creators :) 
`const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => 
    bindActionCreators({
        lectures: setLectures
    }, dispatch); connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Event)` didn't help you? did you bind this action in your component's constructor: `this.props.lectures = this.props.lectures.bind(this)`?

Comment: i glad to be helpful for you @Donios . i think i've made mistake in my code in bindActionCreators function - i've forgotten to pass second parameter to it - `dispatch` i suppose that's why you got type error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169954/discussion-between-arkadiy-afonin-and-donios).